# R: Filter for rows where a value in another row matches a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe of financial data in long format with over 1000 assets and I'm trying to analyze situations where the returns of one stock is affecting the returns of other stocks.
I want to filter a plot to see how the values for one asset are, on the day that the value for another asset is X.

I've created a mock dataframe to illustrate my issue:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

the_date <- c('01-01-1990', '02-01-1990', '03-01-1990', '04-01-1990', '05-01-1990', '01-01-1990', '02-01-1990', '01-01-1990', '02-01-1990','03-01-1990')
the_asset <- c('AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'MSFT','AMZN', 'AMZN', 'AMZN')
the_price <- as.numeric(c(5,6,4,7,8,12,14,50,48,62))
the_returns <- as.numeric(c(0.1, -0.2, 0.14, 0.01, 0.05, -0.002, -0.11, 0.07, 0.08, 0.22))

test_df1 <- data.frame(the_date, the_asset, the_price, the_returns)

test_df1 <- test_df1 %>%
  group_by(the_asset) %>%
  mutate(quartile = ntile(the_returns, n=4))
```

I then plot the returns by quartile in ggplot:

```
test_df1 %>%
  group_by(quartile) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = quartile, y = the_returns)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  ggtitle('Returns by Quartile')
```

I would like to filter this plot in the following manner:

- I want to see the returns by Quartile for 'AAPL' (or any other stock) when the Quartile for 'AMZN' (or any other stock) **on the same date** is 1 (for example, could be 2 or 3)

---

I've thought of making the dataframe into wide format to get each asset as a separate column however I'm not sure if that is the best option or how to proceed exactly.

Comment: What do you mean by another stock's Quartile on the same date (as what?) is 1? Do you mean the Quartiles must equal 1 and the dates between two stocks must be the same?

Comment: The dates between the stocks must be the same yes. The quartile is just a column I created to group the returns into 4 groups but we could just want to filter for the_returns of 'AMZN' is >0 instead of using the quartile

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but on the small dataset it does not return a nice plot, as there are too few rows left after filtering to the conditions you mentioned:

```
test_df1 %>%
  spread(the_asset,quartile, fill=0) %>%
  filter(AMZN==1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(AAPL), y = the_returns)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  ggtitle('Returns by Quartile')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL to approach that (I am sure you can do the same with dplyr, but I am better at sql...).

```
# Add a column with the count of dates that are the same
library(sqldf) # you might have to install other packages to make this one work

test_df1<-sqldf("SELECT count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY the_date) AS SAME_DATE, *  
      FROM test_df1 ")
```

And the plot:

```
ggplot(test_df1,
       aes(
         x = SAME_DATE,
         y = the_returns
         
       
       )) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill =the_asset)) 
  ggtitle('Returns by Quartile')
```

[image]

EDIT: Perhaps this is better:

```
ggplot(test_df1,
       aes(
         x = SAME_DATE,
         y = the_returns
         
       )) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_jitter(aes(shape = the_asset, color = the_asset),size = 4)
ggtitle('Returns by Date')
```

[image]